# Is there a way to create a Cache with different expiration times per-entry

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to use Guava's Caching functionality, but from what I can tell, you can only evict entries based off of total size of the cache (number of entries) or a timed eviction (for the entire cache).  I'd like to have some entries have different expiration times - so I can evict some entries after, say, 1 minute, and other entries after 10 minutes.

Is there some way to specify a field, or a function or something on a cache entry which will have it be evicted if its *individual* expiration has been passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. This is so that expiration can be FIFO, rather than requiring an all-up priority queue.

https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1203 has the discussion on this topic.

Comment: Makes sense.  I think what I will probably investigate doing is creating a ForwardingCache that overrides the get* functions and just checks the expiration time on its way out of the cache.